# Filtering and paging

Tags: jquery, html-lists, paging

Hi people thanks for the help. Im trying to implement a simple pagination that filter, hiding li's by class. The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/11/). I'm new in this but with some help the main idea is working. The only problem is that when i click to filter i wanna paginate just the li's in that category. So if i click in the "category 1" link, the li's with the class "category-2" should be hide and NOT APPEAR when i click next o prev.

HTML

```
<div class="filter">
    <a href="#category-1">category 1</a>
    <a href="#category-2">category 2</a>
</div>

<div id="item-wrapper">
<ul class="items">
    <li class="category-1">item 1</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 2</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 3</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 4</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 5</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 6</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 7</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 8</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 9</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 10</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 11</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 12</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 13</li>
    <li class="category-1">item 14</li>
    <li class="category-2">item 15</li>
</ul>

<div class="ctrl-nav">
<a href="#" id="prev">Previous</a><a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
  $('ul.items li').hide().filter('.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1)).show();

  event.preventDefault();
});


var itemsNumber = 6;
var min = 0;
var max = itemsNumber;

function pagination(action) {

    var totalItems = $("li").length;

    if (max < totalItems) {//Stop action if max reaches more than total items 
        if (action == "next") {

            min = min + itemsNumber;
            max = max + itemsNumber;

        }
    }

    if (min > 0) {//Stop action if min reaches less than 0
        if (action == "prev") {

            min = min - itemsNumber;
            max = max - itemsNumber;

        }
    }

    $("li").hide();
    $("li").slice(min, max).show();

}

pagination();


//Next
$("#next").click(function() {

    action = "next";
    pagination(action);

})

//Previous
$("#prev").click(function() {
    action = "prev";
    pagination(action);

})
```

Any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated your script: http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/12/

Basically, I introduced a new variable `visible` which contained the selected `li` class to show. Then, the `pagination` function handles all the showing/hiding of `li`s. That variable is set to blank by default; thus, all `li`s will show initially. The `pagination` function will start with:

```
var totalItems = $("li" + visible).length;
```

and end with:

```
$("li" + visible).slice(min, max).show();
```

While the click handler is converted to:

```
$('div.filter').delegate('a', 'click', function (event) {
    visible = '.' + this.href.slice(this.href.indexOf("#") + 1);
    pagination();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Sir @alex-r You're the man! Thanks a lot for this awesome answer! PS: Could you show me how to hide "previous" or "next" links when there's nothing more to paginate?. Again Thank you!!!

Comment: I thought you'd never ask: http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/13/ I added checks if the new `max` is greater than `totalItems` and if `min` is less than `0`. Remember to accept this as the answer if it is though ;-)

Comment: +100 @alex-r you're the master!. Nice to meet you and let me tell you today i learn a lot thanks to you :)

Comment: I know this was answered but i guess you're the only one who can save me so this is a last favor so please! im breaking my brain tryng to "fix" a little issue please take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/14/. Now Click in "category 1", and click into "next" until it hide, then click in "Category 3". Like you see the items doesn't show. I don't know if exist some way to go to the first item of the selected category or something that let it be shown.

Comment: @TesterBeta you can modify `pagination` in such a way that whenever the selected category is reset, it goes to the first page of the item list. Currently, it just stays in the same page that's why it doesn't display anything

Comment: Thats the problem @alex-r Sir i dont have idea how to do it!. Sorry im not developer so im really dumb.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12585/discussion-between-tester-beta-and-alex-r)

Comment: 8 years later and I just used this solution for a large list of items (800-1000) that uses a category filter. (I had to update the code a bit, but it works great!) Thanks!