# Pagination and filter script almost ready

Tags: jquery, html-lists, paging

@alex-r help me a lot with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/14/) but im getting a little issue. To understand what im trying to say please click in "category 1" link, now click into "next" until it hide, then click in "Category 3". Like you see the items doesn't show. I don't know if exist some way to go to the first item of the selected category or something that let it be shown.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Reference question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025766/filtering-and-paging/11025878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reset the page to the first one whenever the category is reset.

```
if (action == "first") {
    min = 0;
    max = itemsNumber;
}
```

Then in the `click` event handler, call the `first` action:

```
pagination('first');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vU9Hv/17